# Rename Powershell object property names but keep value

Tags: powershell, object

I have a Powershell Object[] (`$myObject`), I am looking to trim off *sci_* from any object property name that begins with *sci_* but keep the value of the properties

[image: $myObject]

`$myObject.psobject.Properties` does not seem to reveal the property names but found `$myObject | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select-Object Name` does, but havent worked out a way to rename or trim off the *sci_* from the property names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$myObject` variable contains an *array* of objects, so loop over each object in the array to be able to inspect its properties via `.psobject`:

```
$myArray = $myObject |ForEach-Object {
    # prepare dictionary to hold the (renamed) properties
    $newProperties = [ordered]@{}
    foreach($property in $_.psobject.Properties){
        # remove any `sci_` prefix
        $newName = $property.Name -replace '^sci_'
        $newProperties[$newName] = $property.Value
    }

    # create new object based on the renamed properties
    [pscustomobject]$newProperties
}
```

`$myArray` now contains an array of objects just like `$myObject`, except all the objects have had the `sci_` prefix removed from all relevant property names